# how to place splitted array object into root level of elasticsearch doc using logstash split plugin

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration, logstash-filter

I wanna to put splitted array object to the root level of elasticsearch document using split filter plugin on logstash.

Here is my input source, current logstash configuration, output, and output that I wanna get.

**[ INPUT source from my REST API server ]**

```
{
  "rid": "dc755b8d-14bf-4211-a820-9aab01e5475b",
  "rval": {
    "totalCount": 3,
    "data": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Object1",
        "category": "Object1",
        "sequence": 1
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Object2",
        "sequence": 2
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Obect3",
        "sequence": 3
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**[ Logstash Config ]**

```
input {
  http_poller {
    urls => {
      test => {
        method => post
        url => "http://localhost/object"
        body => '{"category": "test"}'
        headers => {
          "Content-Type" => "application/json"
        }
      }
    }
    request_timeout => 60
    schedule => { cron => "* * * * * UTC" }
    codec => "json"
  }
}

filter {
  split {
    field => "[rval][data]"
    target => "test"
  }
  mutate {
    remove_field => [ "rid", "rval", "event", "success", "dateTime", "@version", "@timestamp" ]
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "test"
    # To identify documents, ID of each object must be set to document_id.
    document_id => "%{[test][id]}"
  }
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
}
```

**[ OUTPUT ]**

```
{
  "took": 7,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 3,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 1.0,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "test": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Object1",
            "category": "Object1",
            "sequence": 1
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "test": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Object2",
            "category": "Object2",
            "sequence": 2
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "test": {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Object3",
            "category": "Object3",
            "sequence": 3
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**[ OUTPUT I wanna get ]**

```
{
  "took": 7,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 3,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 1.0,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Object1",
          "category": "Object1",
          "sequence": 1
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Object2",
          "category": "Object2",
          "sequence": 2
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "Object3",
          "category": "Object3",
          "sequence": 3
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The difference is the structure under **hits.hits[]._source**

I want to put splitted array object into **hits.hits[]._source** without "**test**" key.

To get rid of the test key, when I clear the settings below,

> target => "test"

field value(rval.data) is created as a key under **hits.hits[]._source** like below.

```
{
  "took": 7,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 3,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 1.0,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "rval": {
            "totalCount": 3,
            "data": [
              {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Object1",
                "category": "Object1",
                "sequence": 1
              },
              {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Object2",
                "sequence": 2
              },
              {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Obect3",
                "sequence": 3
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

To get output that I expect, how should I modify logstash configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is simply rename the fields

```
filter {
  split {
    field => "[rval][data]"
    target => "test"
  }
  mutate {
    rename => {
       "[test][id]" => "id"
       "[test][name]" => "name"
       "[test][category]" => "category"
       "[test][sequence]" => "sequence"
    }
    remove_field => [ "test", "rid", "rval", "event", "success", "dateTime", "@version", "@timestamp" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Val.
I posted 4 of object fields(id, name, category, sequence) for simple question.
But actually, those are dynamic fields that may or may not be present.
So explicitly declaring the fields that you suggested could not be a fundamental solution for me.
And I've just found the solution a few minutes ago.
Also I'll post that solution here.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Fair enough, it wasn't mentioned in the post that the fields were dynamic... which is not a great idea as it can lead to [mapping explosion](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html#mapping-limit-settings). But glad you found a generic solution

Comment: other than explicitly defining fields or writing ruby script,
isn't there any more other way to place splitted fields at the root level(under **_source**)?

Comment: I thought that there would be such a way because it is just simple process to move the splitted object as it is to the root level.

Answer (score 1):

I just have found the solution.

It was able to be solved the issue by adding some ruby ​​script like below.

```
filter {
  split {
    field => "[rval][data]"
    target => "test"
  }
  ruby {
    code => "event.get('test').each { |k, v| event.set(k, v); event.remove('test');" };
  }
  mutate {
    remove_field => [ "@version", "@timestamp" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you iterate on `test` instead of `[rval][data]` since that's where the fields go?

Comment: You are right Val, It was my miss.
It should be test.
I fixed it. Thanks

Comment: Ok, and you should still remove `test` once all fields have been processed, right?

Comment: Yes, sir. Also I just have added code. **event.remove('test');**

Comment: Ok, you could also add `test` to the `remove_field` array and that does the job too.

Comment: Yes. In this case, adding **event.remove('test');** and putting **test** into remove_field produced same results.